# Feed of all posts from all users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to Implement a feed of all post from a multi user blog. I want to know where to define this method and how to define it to be as "RESTFUL" as possible.

I am thinking of putting it in the posts index view but the problem is i dont have access to the users name attribute that created that post. The index action currently looks like this

```
def index
 @posts = Post.all
end
```

and doing this:

```
def index
 @user=User.find(params[:user_id])
 @posts = @user.posts.all
end
```

raises an error " Couldn't find User without an ID "

App info:
I have a users resource and a post resource (nested in the users). That is pretty much it.
Thanks

Clarification:

Thanks guys for the assistance so far. My controllers index action is defined as follows

```
def index
 @users = User.all
 @posts = @users.collect { |user| user.posts }.flatten
end
```

The issue i am having is displaying the posts users name in the view. for example this works but only displays the posts attibutes:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<ul>
    <li> <%= post.title %>
         <%= post.content %>
         <%= user.name %> or <%= @user,name %> #This does not work
         </li>
</ul>
```

I am not sure if i wrote the block correctly. Hope this clarifies things

Comment: what exactly is wrong with your first example, `@posts = Post.all`?

Comment: Nothing, it appears i made an error in the view instead of calling "post.user.name" i have been putting in "user.name". Very shameful. Sorry for wasting you time. And thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.includes(:user)
end

# view
<ul>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <li>
    <%= post.title %>
    <%= post.content %>
    <%= post.user.name %>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: "post.user.name"  I dont know how i missed that :-( Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should be visiting the wrong URL.

First, check your parameters in your server console, you should not see `user_id` param.

To set this param, use the correct route

```
user_posts_path(an_user_instance)
```

I suppose you have in routes:

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance juanpastas. I have done this. My issue is in my loop to display all posts i will edit my original question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to query the users that you want...

```
def index
# For example...
@users = User.all # or...
@users = User.find_by_group_id(params[:group_id]) # etc...

# Then, from your users, you need to collect the posts...
@posts = @users.collect { |user| user.posts }.flatten
end
```

This would get an array of each users posts, then flatten it to a single array. At that point you can then sort the array to whatever you want.

I don't know what exactly you're looking for, but these are just some ideas. Depending on how you're app is structured (and the groups of users are organized), you'll likely want to use some sorted of nested resource like juanpastas posted.

Comment: You are correct kombo, the issue i am having is I cannot get the users name (user.name or @user.name) to display in the view. I dont know is it is an issue with the way i wrote the block to loop over each post.